# AWS RDS Read Replica: How can I avoid replication of few tables and columns

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, mariadb, amazon-rds

I am a using RDS MariaDB and have a requirement for having a slave DB which I can use for analytics. I am looking for AWS Read Replica but the issue is it doesn't provide me provision for skipping replication of few tables and columns which hold some sensitive information and we don't want to have the slave DB with that information.

Can I skip replication of few tables and columns with the AWS Read Replica? Or in AWS Read Replica can I write AWS Lambda which can delete this information from Replica DB?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[AWS Database Migration Service](https://aws.amazon.com/dms/) would work for this use case:

- You can use the AWS Database Migration Service to establish ongoing continuous replication between heterogeneous source and target databases.
- AWS DMS supports MariaDB for both source and target databases.
- AWS DMS supports per-table selection from the source database.
- AWS DMS supports removing columns during transformation to the target database.

Per the FAQ:

> Q. In addition to one-time data migration, can I use AWS Database
> Migration Service for continuous data replication?
>
> Yes, you can use AWS Database Migration Service for both one-time data
> migration into RDS and EC2-based databases as well as for continuous
> data replication. AWS Database Migration Service will capture changes
> on the source database and apply them in a transactionally-consistent
> way to the target. Continuous replication can be done from your data
> center to the databases in AWS or in the reverse, replicating to a
> database in your datacenter from a database in AWS. Ongoing continuous
> replication can also be done between homogenous or heterogeneous
> databases. For ongoing replication it would be preferable to use
> Multi-AZ for high-availability.

If you aren't familiar with AWS DMS, take a look at the official documentation '[Getting Started](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_GettingStarted.html)' pages, and then continue below.

---

Create your target database with an identical schema as the source except for these few tables and columns that you do not want to populate.

Once you've associated your source and target databases with DMS, you'll want to create a task to perform the migration, with specific table mappings to exclude tables and remove columns.

### Excluding Tables

Create a [selection rule](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Tasks.CustomizingTasks.TableMapping.html#CHAP_Tasks.CustomizingTasks.TableMapping.SelectionTransformation.Selections) with rule-action exclude, and specify which tables you want to exclude. Example from the documentation that migrates all tables except those with tablenames starting with `DMS%`:

```
{
    "rules": [
        {
            "rule-type": "selection",
            "rule-id": "1",
            "rule-name": "1",
            "object-locator": {
                "schema-name": "Test",
                "table-name": "%"
            },
            "rule-action": "include"
        },
        {
            "rule-type": "selection",
            "rule-id": "2",
            "rule-name": "2",
            "object-locator": {
                "schema-name": "Test",
                "table-name": "DMS%"
            },
            "rule-action": "exclude"
        }
    ]
}
```

### Removing Columns

Create a [transformation rule](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Tasks.CustomizingTasks.TableMapping.html#CHAP_Tasks.CustomizingTasks.TableMapping.SelectionTransformation.Transformations) with rule-action remove and rule-target any specify the schema, table, and column names of the column that you want to remove.  The following example, also from the documentation, removes all columns from the test.Actor table that begin with the characters `col`:

```
{
    "rules": [{
        "rule-type": "selection",
        "rule-id": "1",
        "rule-name": "1",
        "object-locator": {
            "schema-name": "test",
            "table-name": "%"
        },
        "rule-action": "include"
    }, {
        "rule-type": "transformation",
        "rule-id": "2",
        "rule-name": "2",
        "rule-action": "remove-column",
        "rule-target": "column",
        "object-locator": {
            "schema-name": "test",
            "table-name": "Actor",
            "column-name": "col%"
        }
    }]
 }
```

### Further Reading

- [AWS Database Migration Service FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/dms/faqs/)
- [AWS DMS Documentation - Using Table Mapping with an Task to Select and Filter Data](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Tasks.CustomizingTasks.TableMapping.html)
- [AWS DMS Documentation - Using a MySQL-Compatible Database as a Source for AWS DMS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.MySQL.html)
- [AWS DMS Documentation - Working with AWS DMS Tasks](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Tasks.html)

Comment: That fits perfectly to my requirement. Thank You!!

Answer (score 2):

An RDS Read Replica is read-only. You cannot directly modify this replica.

A better approach would be to create the appropriate table and column level permissions so that the analytics users cannot access certain tables.

[MySQL Table and Column Level Permissions](https://support.chartio.com/knowledgebase/mysql-table-level-permissions)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, user with specific grants is not an option for us. The hard requirement is it should not replicate and that's why I am am looking for certain configurations in AWS itself.

Comment: *"An RDS Read Replica is read-only. You cannot directly modify this replica."*  This is not, technically speaking, true.  By modifying the parameter group, you can make an RDS replica writable... at your own peril, of course.  Doing this temporarily is handy for adding replica-only indexes, which is valid as long as they aren't unique indexes (which would not make sense).  If the columns to suppress are the rightmost columns of the tables, they can actually be dropped on a replica without breaking replication. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-features-differing-tables.html

Comment: @Michael. Technically you can set read_only to 0. This is not something that I would recommend to a customer for normal production environments. I would reserve this for certain repair and recovery operations.

Comment: I agree, which is why I said "technically."  Technically, it's possible to avoid replicating certain columns or tables, but it's almost always delicate and almost never a good idea.  +1 for appropriate permissions.